# How to set log level for a RabbitMQ plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

According to https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html#log-message-categories I can set log levels for certain categories in RabbitMQ.

Now I want to set the log level of a specific plugin (namely `rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2`) to debug, is this possible?
If so, how can this be achieved?